# Почему в FireBase отправляется push, а на устройства он не приходит?

Tags: kotlin, firebase

Убил весь день на то, почему же на мои устройства Android push-уведомления не приходят.

До сих пор понять не могу, но объясню суть: есть мобильное приложение, которое написано на Kotlin, оно подключено к FireBase и работает исправно, вся статистка отображается и работает правильно, но когда я отправляю уведомления на мои устройства они не приходят, при чем выходит, что они отправились успешно на устройства, но на устройствах нету никаких уведомлений. Может, что я что-то упустил?

Comment: Ну хотелось бы видеть какой-то код. Откуда уверенность что все подключено и работает исправно? Как вообще можно понять в чем у вас ошибка

Comment: Firebase статистика еще не говорит о том, что пуши интегрированы. При дефолтной интеграции приложение должно быть свернуто, чтобы отобразилось уведомление.